# how can i pass input data of popup box by onclick into jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to enter password by `onclick` of Javascript and then, pass the password value to `JSP` file to store its Domain.

```
input id=save type=button onClick="password=prompt('Enter your password');"
```

How can I pass this password value in pop box to JSP or User Domain ?

Or can I use jquery for this function? 
Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
<input id="save" type="button" onClick="if (pass = prompt('Enter your password')) { $('#password').val(pass); }">

<input type="hidden" name="password" id="password">
```